# Why does adding 1.0/3.0 numeric literal three times evaluates to exactly 1 in Golang?

Tags: go, floating-point, cpu, floating-accuracy

The StackOverflow answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48095871/why-adding-1-0-3-0-three-times-works-just-as-mathematically-expected) is very complex for a beginner like me.

Executing the following line of code in Golang results into **1**

```
fmt.Println(1.0/3.0 + 1.0/3.0 + 1.0/3.0)
```

According to my knowledge, 1.0/3.0 results into 0.3333333... which cannot be stored accurately then what causes this result.

I am not acquainted with low things like how a processor or CPU executes a particular instruction. Can anyone give me a simple answer?

Comment: https://golang.org/ref/spec#Constant_expressions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [The Go Programming Language Specification](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Constant_expressions), “Constant expressions are always evaluated exactly…” This means the compiler (or other implementation) is required to do full real-number arithmetic to the extent required to evaluate a constant expression. Thus `1.0/3.0 + 1.0/3.0 + 1.0/3.0` is evaluated as ⅓ + ⅓ + ⅓, which is of course 1.